# Laravel Mix npm run watch fails

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-5

I'm trying to compile laravel sass files to apply the changes but every time i run (`npm run watch`) or (`npm run dev`) i get these errors...

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-01-01T14_42_14_962Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-01-01T14_42_15_042Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this error is there are no **node_modules**.

As the [Laravel Mix Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#installation) states:

You have to run **npm install** to download all the required packages for Laravel Mix.

If you have **node_module** folder then delete it and run **npm install** again.

Answer (score 1):

vue-loader is a loader for webpack that allows you to author Vue components in a format.
Please run the command.

```
npm i vue-loader
```